# Jquery remove selected div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

```
  <div id="a_all">
  <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="m_a">1</input<br></div>
  <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="m_a">2</input<br></div>
  <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="m_a">3</input<br></div>
  <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="m_a">4</input<br></div>
  </div>
```

If the first check box is selected how to remove the full div the checkbox in using jquery

Comment: Your HTML code seems broken. There is no ending ´>´ for the `</input>` ending tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hi rajiv**

Try this

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="all">
        <div>1<input type=checkbox name="test" value="10"/></div>
        <div>2<input type=checkbox name="test" value="20"/></div>
        <div>3<input type=checkbox name="test" value="30"/></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
​
```

jquery

```
$("#all input").click(function() {
    alert($("input:checked").val());
    $(this).parent().remove();
});​
```

live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/QpEVe/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').bind('change',_handleCheckboxChange);

function _handleCheckboxChange(e)
{
   var _elm=jQuery(e.target);
   if(_elm.filter(':checked'))
   {
       _elm.parents('div:first').remove()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to bind the click even to each checkbox. It will remove the parent element of each checkbox you click:

```
$(function(){
  $('#a_all :checkbox').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```